# Laravel : Redirect directly to a page without returning back to previous function

Tags: php, laravel

This is HelperController I made for general functions to be used by all controllers

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Session;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HelperController extends Controller
{

public function UploadImage($UploadImage,$folder)
{
    if($UploadImage->isValid() && $UploadImage->getMaxFilesize()>=$UploadImage->getSize())
    {
        if($UploadImage->guessExtension()=='jpeg' || $UploadImage->guessExtension()=='jpg' || $UploadImage->guessExtension()=='gif' || $UploadImage->guessExtension()=='png')
        {
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/assets/images/'.$folder.'/';
            $uploadedFilename = time().'_'.$UploadImage->getClientOriginalName();
            $UploadImage->move($destinationPath,$uploadedFilename);

            return $uploadedFilename;
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/profile')->with('errorMessage','Extension Issue');
            // or
            // return back()->with('errorMessage','Extension Issue');
            // or
            // return "extension";
        }
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/profile')->with('errorMessage','Size Issue');
        // or
        // return back()->with('errorMessage','Size Issue');
        // or
        // return "size";
    }
}

public function beautifyRole($role)
{
    return ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$role));
}

}
```

This is the Profile Controller I am using the UploadImage function from the HelperController to upload the image

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

public function UpdateProfile(Request $request)
{

    $User = User::where('id',Auth::User()->id)->first();

    $User->name = $request->Input('name');
    $User->email = $request->Input('email');
    $User->password = bcrypt($request->Input('password'));

    // Check if New Avatar if Uploaded
    if($request->avatar!=null){
        $HelpUpload = new HelperController;
        $avatar = $HelpUpload->UploadImage($request->avatar,'users');

        /*
        if($avatar=='size'){
            return back()->with('errorMessage','File Size Issue');
        } elseif($avatar=='extension'){
            return back()->with('errorMessage','File Extension Issue');
        } else {
            $User->avatar = $avatar;
        }
        */
    }

    $User->save();

    return Redirect('/profile')->with('successMessage','Profile Updated Successfully');

}

}
```

But there is a issue if Size or Extension condition is not met, I want the page redirects to previous page or directly to profile page. Instead it goes back to UploadProfile Function and always shows "Profile Updated Succesfully" Message even if any error occurs.

I want to remove the control structure on the UpdateProfile Function. It works when I return a error message and then check it on the Update Profile Function.

Can we directly redirect to the profile page from the UploadImage function in HelperController without returning back to preivous function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`redirect()->back()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects) method along with the error message if your image upload function doesn't work like as

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors("Your error message");
```